# Bargain Finder Max V4

Tags: postman, sabredav

Using Bargain Finder Max V4 API, and I've encountered situation where API response provides `'statistics': {'itineraryCount': 0}`. Despite ensuring that all necessary variables and parameters are correct.

I used all parameters that are necessary but I did not got any real time itinerary response. This is my body:

```json
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [
      {
        "RPH": "1",
        "DepartureDateTime": "2023-11-24T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "DXB",
          "LocationType": "C"
        },
        
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LHE",
          "LocationType": "C"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
          "CabinPref": {
            "Cabin": "Y",
            "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "POS": {
      "Source": [
        {
          "PseudoCityCode": "",
          "RequestorID": {
            "CompanyName": {
              "Code": "TN"
            },
            "ID": "1",
            "Type": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
      "AirTravelerAvail": [
        {
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
            {
              "Code": "ADT",
              "Quantity": 1
              
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Version": "V4"
  }
}
```